# Unable to authenticate using Firebase Open ID Connect as Amazon Cognito Authentication Provider

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have added Firebase as an open id connect authentication provider on Amazon Cognito following the steps listed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989039/using-firebase-openid-connect-provider-as-aws-iam-identity-provider)

In my logins map when I use the key "securetoken.google.com/firebaseprojectid" it gives me NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Couldn't verify signed token.
When I use "https://securetoken.google.com/firebaseprojectid" it says issuer and provider do not match.

The iss field of the ID Token as decoded by jwt.io contains "https://securetoken.google.com/firebaseprojectid"

Comment: Can you PM me the request Id, identity pool Id and the timeframe when you got this error?

Comment: Send me an email to abhinavshrivastava2@gmail.com, since there is no way to PM you on Stackoverflow

Comment: @AbhinavShrivastava Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No I haven't been able to solve it