# Firebase Authentication via OpenID Connect

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, openid-connect

I would like to authenticate users against Firebase Authentication via OpenID Connect. In other words:

- create a Firebase project
- add users under authentication
- get an issuer URL for my project that implements OIDC Discovery
- get a clientID
- use the issuer URL and the clientID in my app that acts as an OIDC client to retrieve information / id_token for users in the Firebase Project

The documentation does not mention this possibility, so I'd understand if this was not possible.

However:

- using OIDC is quite the standard way to do these things
- there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989039/using-firebase-openid-connect-provider-as-aws-iam-identity-provider) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143700/unable-to-authenticate-using-firebase-open-id-connect-as-amazon-cognito-authenti) post that actually tell me this is/was possible
- the OIDC discovery document they mention is actually available my project too, although it is incomplete (missing the endpoint URLs)
- digging in the GC dev console it seems like OAuth2 is used internally in the Firebase SDK - newly created service accounts inherit some callback URLs that belong to my Firebase project

Implementing my own IDP using Firebase Auth seems to be an overkill, especially that it might already be available.

Any hints anyone?

Comment: Hi. Sorry to bump an old topic but did you find a way to solve your problem ?

Comment: Nope, I abandoned the idea, integrated with the SDK instead.

Comment: This is mind boggling, looks like this still isn't supported, the public keys are published just not in the OpenID format. https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old question but I'm surprised no one has answered this.

With Firebase you have the choice of using the simpler Firebase Auth or the more comprehensive [Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) to authenticate your users and [Identity Platform does support OIDC](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc) authentication.

[Here's a comparison of the differences.](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison)

Identity Platform just simply needs to be enabled for your project and it will begin authenticating users without changing a line of code. Both services utilize the same Firebase JS SDK for authentication making the transition easy.

The only "downside" is that the Identity Platform isn't free, but does have a very generous free tier.

Comment: What you are describing is how to sign in via a federated provider while using the Firebase or Google Identity SDKs. IIUC what OP was asking for is the reverse: that he wants the user directory to be in Firebase, and then simply point his OIDC-compliant app to a Firebase `/well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint to make it work.

Comment: +1 to what Pieter said. Whilst what you say is entirely correct, it does not answer the OPs question at all, which is about how to use OIDC protocols from your app to use Firebase as an IDP

Comment: @Brian Burton Do you have any idea how to implement this in Flutter?

Comment: @AgileZebra Identity Platform supports rolling your own IDP if you believe that's the OP's ultimate goal.  Feel free to provide your own answer if you feel mine to be incorrect.

Comment: @BrianBurton. I don't have my own answer. I came here looking for the the answer to the same question as the OP was.